# How to Insert data to tables having references each other in ORDBMS?

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, object-relational-model

```
CREATE TYPE Dept_t1
/
CREATE TYPE Emp_t1 AS OBJECT(
 eno number(4), 
 ename varchar2(15), 
 edept ref dept_t1, 
 salary number(8,2));
/
CREATE TYPE Dept_t1 AS OBJECT(
 dno number(2), 
 dname varchar2(12), 
 mgr ref emp_t1);
/
CREATE TYPE Proj_t1 AS OBJECT(
 pno number(4),
 pname varchar2(15), 
 pdept ref dept_t1, 
 budget number(10,2));
/

CREATE TABLE Emp1 OF Emp_t1(
 eno PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Dept1 OF Dept_t1(
 dno PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Proj1 OF Proj_t1(
 pno PRIMARY KEY
);
ALTER TABLE Emp1 MODIFY (edept REFERENCES Dept1);
ALTER TABLE Dept1 MODIFY (mgr REFERENCES Emp1);
ALTER TABLE Proj1 MODIFY (pdept REFERENCES dept1);
INSERT INTO Emp1 VALUES(1,'A',(SELECT REF(d) FROM Dept1 d where d.dno=11),30)
/
INSERT INTO Emp1 VALUES(2,'B',(SELECT REF(d) FROM Dept1 d where d.dno=12),50)
/
INSERT INTO Dept1 VALUES(11,'D1',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Emp1 e where e.eno=1))
/
INSERT INTO Dept1 VALUES(12,'D2',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Emp1 e where e.eno=2))
/
INSERT INTO Proj1 VALUES(111,'P1',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Dept1 e where e.dno=11),25)
/
INSERT INTO Proj1 VALUES(112,'P2',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Dept1 e where   e.dno=12),35)
/
```

When I am trying to execute following query,
  SELECT p.pname,p.pdept.dno FROM Proj1 p WHERE p.budget>45

p.pdept.dno column is get empty. How to resolve that problem? I was already added all the values. But not sure why null values get displayed. I am new to object relational database management system. So I need a help from all of you.

Dept1 table image is as this.
[image]

Comment: We'll need to see the inserts done on the `Dept1` table to be of much help.

Comment: Updated the answer as you mentioned

Comment: This looks to be a simple typo. You don't have a `DNO` in `DEPT` that is 1 or 2, they're 11 and 12. You also don't have a `BUDGET` or greater than 45 anywhere. If your final insert statements are as follows you everything works: `INSERT INTO Proj1 VALUES(113,'P1',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Dept1 e where e.dno = 11),25);
    INSERT INTO Proj1 VALUES(114,'P2',(SELECT REF(e) FROM Dept1 e where e.dno = 12),45);`

Comment: By a mistake I entered as 1 or 2 instead 11 and 12. Now I have editted. And I didn't post all the insert query statements. That's why you can't see budget values greater than 45 anywhere. So still same problem appears Ben.